# Moving data from related remote tables over DB link

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

There're are two remote tables A_REM and B_REM with foreign key relationship but without foreign key constraint and about 10,000 new rows in table A_REM and 50,000 in table B_REM *per day*. The most operations are inserts. Now I would like to move the data from A_REM and B_REM to local tables A_LOC and B_LOC with locking the rows while processing. After moving, the rows should be deleted in tables A_REM and B_REM.

```
A_REM    B_REM
1 ----- |_ 1
        |_ 2
        |_ 3
--------------------
2 ----- |_ 4
        |_ 5 rows 2 and 4-6 are locked while moving
        |_ 6
--------------------
3 ----- |_ 7
        |_ 8
        |_ 9
```

What is the best way to move the data while keeping the relationship between data from table A_REM and B_REM (consistency). If I had only one table, I would use the "FOR UPDATE OF" statement in conjunction with a cursor (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#CHDGEHBF).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to build your own replication solution.  Is there a reason that you're not leveraging any of Oracle's built-in replication technologies?  Could you, for example, create a materialized view on the local system and a materialized view log on the remote system rather than maintaining a separate change table?  Could you use Streams or CDC?

Comment: Yes, a standard replication solution would be the best way. But at the moment it's not possible to establish one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one remote database in the transaction, it is not a distributed transaction so it behaves identically as a local transaction (as opposed to a distributed transaction across multiple remote databases).  The following example shows how you can obtain the proper row-level locks and move the data in a single unit of work with the data consistency you require.

```
create table a_rem ( aid number, acontent varchar2(10) );
create table b_rem ( bid number, aid number, bcontent varchar(10) );

create table a_loc ( aid number, acontent varchar2(10) );
create table b_loc ( bid number, aid number, bcontent varchar(10) );

insert into a_rem values ( 1, 'A-One' );
insert into a_rem values ( 2, 'A-Two' );
insert into a_rem values ( 3, 'A-Three' );

insert into b_rem values ( 1, 1, 'B-One' );
insert into b_rem values ( 2, 1, 'B-Two' );
insert into b_rem values ( 3, 2, 'B-Three' );
insert into b_rem values ( 4, 3, 'B-Four' );
insert into b_rem values ( 5, 3, 'B-Five' );

commit;
-- look Ma, no data integrity! :(

-- let us pretend I want to move a_rem.aid = 2 information from both tables
declare
   cursor row_level_locks is 
   select a.*, b.* 
     from a_rem a, b_rem b 
    where a.aid = b.aid and a.aid = 2 
      for update;
begin
   open row_level_locks; -- begins transaction, obtains proper row level locking
   insert into a_loc select * from a_rem where aid = 2;
   insert into b_loc select * from b_rem where aid = 2;
   delete a_rem where aid = 2;
   delete b_rem where aid = 2;
   commit;
   close row_level_locks;
end;
```

Final note: If data integrity is important between the two tables, go ahead and create that foreign key constraint on B_REM referencing A_REM. If you can't/won't then data integrity is not important. It can't both be important and a trivial step to ensure it not taken.